# How to access child controller data from parent view in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have an ionic view like this -

```
<ion-nav-bar class="header-panel" align-title="center">
    <h1 class="title offer-title">Title 1</h1>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-tabs class="tabs-royal">
    <ion-tab title="Tab 1" href="#/somelink1">
        <ion-nav-view name="someview1"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Tab 2" href="#/somelink2">
        <ion-nav-view name="someview2"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

The `someview1` and `someview2` are bound to their respective controllers, but they can represent data dynamically, say with `Id=1` or `Id=2` or `Id=3` and so on.

How can I access this Id information which the tabs hold in the parent level so I can change nav bar title dynamically like `Title 1` or `Title 2` or `Title 3` respectively.

Essentially what I am asking is can we have a top level controller which holds information what child level controller data is?

**Note:** The routes are set-up using `ui-router`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a service to do this.  You can inject the service into any controller and they can all update it.

Comment: If you have an object on a parent scope, child scope can access it (read). https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: @BorisCharpentier do you mean to say that we can attach a controller to let's say ion-nav-bar element and angular would know that someview1controller is its child? Or do we require to inject it too in child controllers to access it? Sorry, I am new to this, but an example would help.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Why are we sure that the service would have the latest copy of the model that is changing in views bound to those controllers?

Comment: @Sam I don't know if I understand your question, but Angular will handle this automatically with data bindings: http://jsfiddle.net/dL3vgn1s/

Answer (score 1):

Use a service (this will be your model) it is singleton so it will hold a consistent data.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can and you should be able to pass it down through the child controllers using the `resolve` functionality of `ui-router`

See documentation for more details [What Do Child States Inherit From Parent States?](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#what-do-child-states-inherit-from-parent-states)